# Set ng-init for select if ngModel refers to a "getter/setter" function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select component which should be set by default to `allDates[0]`. How to do it using ng-init if ng-model is not a value itself, it is binded to getter/setter function?

```
$scope.selectedDate = function (value) {
    return someFunc(value);
}
```

```
<select class="date-select"
    ng-model="selectedDate" 
    ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"
    ng-options="date for date in allDates">
</select>
```

I've tried `ng-init="allDates[0]"/ "selectedDate(allDates[0])"`. But they don't work.

Comment: You can't pass a function reference to ngModel. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. See [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Comment: Instead of using the `getterSetter` option, consider using the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive.